# Namespaces for image editing in .net 4.5 framework

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing, .net-4.5

I am aware of `System.Drawing` and `System.Windows.Media`

But I have read mentions of .net wrappers for `DirectUI` or `DirectX` and that there may be new namespaces for image editing in .net 4.5

Is this true? Are there any other or new namespaces for image editing in .net 4.5?

I don't think `System.Drawing` facilitates my needs, `System.Windows.Media` might. I have been trying to get an overview of image editing for over a week now. I have searched the web. Most of the information is old or unclear. I need a clear up to date overview of the current namespaces for image editing built into .net 4.5

Comment: You weren't clear on what you were trying to achieve or features needed in terms of "image editing", but perhaps the WriteableBitmapExtensions can help you in that regard: http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there were any (significant) changes made in .net 4.5 about image manipulation.

Im not sure what kind of images you want to manipulate.

**If your images are not photographs and you can use vector graphic** - maybe you should read about SVG manipulation. It may be a good choice for rendering charts or diagrams.

[Build Flexible, Lightweight XML-Based Images for ASP.NET Using Scalable Vector Graphics
(by Dennis Forbes at MSDN Magazine)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164114.aspx)

**If you want to edit photographs or some other complicated images** - you may use [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/features/) framework, which is well developed and popular library with GPL/LGPL license.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I'm interested in working with raster images. I would like to be able to create blank images, assign the image a colour profile, paint on the image, manipulate the image and save the image.